# create multiple folders in a directory

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, exists, mkdir

I want to create multiple folders within themselves. If I have 3 folder I want to make on my desktop nested within each other. I want create the directory `'C:/Users/User/Desktop/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/'` the way I currently do this is I call `os.path.exists()` and  `os.mkdir()` multiple times. Is there a way to do this without having to call these multiple times?

```
import os

DIR = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/'
if not os.path.exists(DIR):
    os.mkdir(DIR)
DIR = DIR + 'folder_b/'
if not os.path.exists(DIR):
    os.mkdir(DIR)
DIR = DIR + 'folder_c/'
if not os.path.exists(DIR):
    os.mkdir(DIR)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create multiple nested folders in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45141147/how-to-create-multiple-nested-folders-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we only need to do one check :) As `folder_b` can not exist if `folder_a` is not present.

Which brings us to the 2nd scenario. For which we leave out `exist_ok=True` for the appropriate check to be made again, but for the inclusion of `folder_b` and 'folder_c' if neither exist.

**Option 1:**

```
from os import (
    makedirs,
    path,
)

dir_path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/folder_a/{}'

if path.exists(dir_path):
    makedirs(
        dir_path.format(
            'folder_b/folder_c/',
        )
    )
```

**Option 2:**

```
from os import makedirs

dir_path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c'
makedirs(dir_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a recursive function for you:

```
import os

DIR = './folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/'

def make_nested_folders(DIR):
  print(DIR)
  if "/" in DIR:
    DIR, last = DIR.rsplit("/", 1)
    make_nested_folders(DIR)
  else:
    last = DIR
  if last and not os.path.exists(last):
    os.mkdir(last)

make_nested_folders(DIR)
```